# Gauss theorem: $\vec{v} = (x^2 + ye^z, y^2 + ze^x , z^2 + x e^y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

If D is the region bounded by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1, z=0$ and $z= x+2$, use the Gauss Theorem to evaluate 
$$ \iint_S \vec{v} . \vec{n} \; dS$$
where $S$ is $\partial D$ , $\vec{n} $ points to the exterior of the surface and $\vec{v} = (x^2 + ye^z, y^2 + ze^x , z^2 + x e^y)$

**My attempt**

Using spherical coordinates, the double integral would be evaluate calculate the triple integral over the region

$$(r, \theta, z) \in (0,1) \times (0, 2 \pi) \times (0, 2 + r \cos \theta)$$

of the function

$$ 2x + 2y + 2z, (x,y,z) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, z)$$

But my integral is evaluating $19 \pi /4$ and the answer is $5 \pi$. is the integration domain wrong?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I get $\frac{19\pi}{4}$ also. Why is the answer $5\pi$ ?

Comment: I meant, the book answer. Probably it is wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah the answers is the backs of calculus books often contain errors.